# How to get the value of one of the attributes used by Backpack?

Tags: laravel-5.3, laravel-backpack

For example, I need to take the "**id**" value and use it to do a search for my model Article, but this value (id) which also appears in the URL: "/article/**4**/edit" and in the "setColumns" parameters, I don't have any idea how to get it.

I need your help.
This is my sample code:

**ArticleCrudController.php**

```
public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();

    $this->crud->setModel('App\Models\Article');
    $this->crud->setRoute("admin/article");
    $this->crud->setEntityNameStrings('article', 'articles');

    $this->crud->setColumns(['id', 'title', 'text']);

    // WHERE ARE YOU ID?!?!!!
    $article = Article::findOrFail($id);
    $pictures = $article->picture()->first()->name;

    $this->crud->addFields([
        [
            'name' => 'title',
            'label' => 'Title',
            'type' => 'Text'
        ],
        [
            'name' => 'text',
            'label' => 'Text',
            'type' => 'ckeditor'
        ],
        [   // Browse
            'name' => 'image',
            'label' => 'Article immage',
            'type' => 'browse',
            'value' => $pictures //Obviously without id don't work :'(
        ]

    ]);

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try to override the `CrudController::edit` method to which is passed the id as first parameter.

```
public function edit($id)
{
    $articlePicture = Article::findOrFail($id)->picture()->first()->name;

    $this->crud->addField([
        'name' => 'image',
        'value' => $articlePicture
    ]);

    return parent::edit($id);
}
```

This could be a solution but I'm not sure it's the right way to do what you want.

Comment: Isn't the exact way but it is the perfect way! You have solved all of my problems! You are a genius! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 4):

Use getCurrentEntry to get the current model object in crud

```
$article_id = $this->crud->getCurrentEntry()->id;
```

Answer (score 0):

As of 2023, Federico Liva's answer doesn't quite work. Swears at parent::edit($id);

Because the working version

```
public function setupUpdateOperation()
{
         $actual_model =$this->crud->getCurrentEntry();
         dd($actual_model->id);
}
```